# Esprima detect global scope access

Tags: javascript, security

Is it possible with esprima (or other similar tools) to 100% detect if a piece of untrusted code tries to access variables outside the function scope it runs in?

```
window.foo = 5
var func = new Function('"use strict"; console.log(foo);')
func.call(null)
```

This would log 5. I can prevent **this** from being available in the function with func.call(null) and prepending "use strict" to the untrusted code.

I assume I could also analyze the code with esprima, or even eslint and detect the variables that don't exist in the func svope, am I right? Is it 100% secure? I know the code could still misbehave and for instance do a while(true){}, but aside from long running code like is it "scope secure"?

Comment: Note that `console` is a "variable outside the function scope it runs in" too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume I could also analyze the code with esprima, or even eslint and detect the variables that don't exist in the func scope, am I right?

Yes.

> Is it 100% secure?

No, not at all. Consider `new {}.constructor.constructor("alert('evil!')")()`, which does not access *any* variables.

Comment: That is indeed evil. I was going to make the point that Esprima is a parser that can produce a syntax tree enabling static analysis, but static analysis cannot be used to determine what the code will do once run. :-)

Comment: Could I not detect access to constructor as well?

Comment: @MartinHansen Not with static analysis, no. You need a complete sandbox solution for untrusted code.

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi pointed out, this is not secure at all. If you want to run untrusted code, you can try this [sandbox](http://gf3.github.io/sandbox/).

Example:

```
var s = new Sandbox()
s.run( '1 + 1 + " apples"', function( output ) {
  // output.result == "2 apples"
})
```