# What does Object.constructor.constructor('alert(1)')() actually do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, security

I am involved in Application security and often times I've used

```
 {{constructor.constructor('alert(1)')()}}
```

blindly in AngularJS applications to escape the sandbox in older versions. Recently I've been trying to understand what this really means and how it works. I tried reading about object constructors and understand that an object constructor points to the object type. so for example.

```
var a = new String;
console.log(a.constructor);
```

will print out `String` and if I do `a.constructor.constructor` this will print out {}

Now my question is how does `object.constructor.constructor('ANY FUNCTION HERE')()` lead to that function being executed in javascript

Comment: `Object.constructor.constructor === Function`

Comment: [Object.constructor===Object.constructor.constructor // why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963547)

Comment: Also related: [Decode this strange Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9045701) | [Is there a way to jail in Javascript, so that the DOM isn't visible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2673695) | [Securing JavaScript eval function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26482268) | [Esprima detect global scope access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48748584)